# Error INSERT en RDS con Python

Tags: mysql, python, amazon-rds

Tengo un problema que creo que es bastante sencillo pero no logro ver cual es mi error.

Estoy intentando rellenar una tabla muy simple usando la librería Faker en Python. Estoy usando como RDBMS AWS RDS con Amazon Aurora y compatibilidad con MySQL.

Como digo, la tabla es muy muy simple:

```
CREATE TABLE FakeUsers (
    UserID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(200),
    Address VARCHAR(200)    
)
```

Y el código que estoy usando para hacer inserciones es:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
sql_statement = f'INSERT INTO FakeUsers (Name, Address) VALUES ("{fake.name()}", "{fake.address()}" )'
%sql $sql_statement;
```

El error que me salta es:

```
(pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Williams, 6438 Luis Corner Suite 975\nLake Jonathanfort, MO 21926 )' at line 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO FakeUsers (Name, Address) VALUES (Amy Williams, 6438 Luis Corner Suite 975
Lake Jonathanfort, MO 21926 );]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Parece que el error es de sintaxis a la hora de formar la sentencia de INSERT INTO... Si hago un print de la variable sql_statement veo que la sintaxis es correcta, y si copio el resultado del print y lo pego en un cliente de SQL estilo DBeaver o SQL Management, se inserta sin problemas.

Anterior a este fragmento de código he cargado las librerias ipython-sql y pymysql, y he conectado correctamente con RDS.

¿En dónde estoy fallando? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro, pero podría ser por el salto de línea en la dirección (`fake.address()`). Prueba esta sintaxis, que es más segura además:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO FakeUsers (Name, Address) VALUES (%s, %s)'
cursor.execute(sql, (fake.name(), fake.address()))
```

Esta sintaxis con los placeholders evita sql injection y la puedes encontrar en la [documentación de PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/).

Comment: Lo probé y me funciona si lo hago de esa manera! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Acepta la respuesta si funciona, gracias :)